# Using CSS display property instead of HTML hyperlinks

Tags: html, css

I have a profile menu with the  following elements:

```
    <div id="tabs">
 <ul id="mnba">
  <li><a  href="#">Personal</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#">Education</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#">Work</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">Photos</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

instead of using HTML hyperlinks to direct the user to different pages to edit a certain information from the menu, I want to use the same page to display all menu elements using just CSS display property. is this a good practice?

Comment: Please specify your question; do you want to hide / display information seperately on one page?

Comment: Why would the user edit information on your profile? I don't understand the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the concept is really good it will be easy for a user to switch from one to another which is quite efficient,effective and easy for use.
HMTL is just a body you can style links as your will